# grouping contained models

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.2

```
PresentationView hasMany SlideView
```

`SlideView` model has field duration.

The presentation_duration = sum of all `SlideView.duration` fields from slide views that belong to the presentation.

I want to get list (paged) of presentations with presentation_duration for each presentation.
So far I am trying like this:

```
$this->paginate['contain'] = array(
            'PresentationView' => array(
                'SlideView' => array(
                    'group' => 'SlideView.presentation_view_id',
                                    // 'conditions' => array('group' => 'SlideView.presentation_view_id'),
                )
            )
        );
```

The commented line is an option that I tried.

Both methods end up with some SQL errors:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'SlideView.group' in 'fieldlist'

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'group' in 'where clause'
```

It seems that `contain` doesn not even recognize `group` key - is it even possible to use grouping like this? If yes how I can do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot pass 'group' to your 'contain'.  To do what you're hoping to do, you'll need to use JOINs - see [CakePHP Joining Tables](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables).